# Configure mod_rewritte for two hosts in Lighttpd

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I have a problem configuring mod_rewrite in two hosts with Lighttpd.

I have one which is a newer version of the old. The old doesn't use `mod_rewrite`, while the new one does. However, the problem is that if I enable the module in `lighttpd.conf` then, the old one make all the redirects, even when I'm not configuring it to have any redirect.

This is my conf file:

```
$HTTP["host"]=~"test.org" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/virtual/acruz/www/public/"
    server.errorlog      = "/var/www/virtual/acruz/logs/error.log"
    accesslog.filename   = "/var/www/virtual/acruz/logs/access.log"

    url.rewrite-once = (
        ".*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|)$" => "$0",
        "^/.*(\?.*)"                     => "/index.php$1",
        ""                               => "/index.php"
    )
}

$HTTP["host"]=~"r5.test.org" {
    server.document-root   = "/var/www/virtual/acruz/r5/"
    server.errorlog        = "/var/www/virtual/acruz/logs/error.log"
    accesslog.filename     = "/var/www/virtual/acruz/logs/access.log"
    setenv.add-environment = ("env" => "acruz")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace `=~` with `==` for both host ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as j0k said, use better host matching - `=~"test.org" matches "r5.test.org" too.

also you can have only one `server.errorlog` (you don't get a config warning/error yet, but it will use only one of the configured files).